# all goroutines are asleep deadlock

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

I am trying to play around with goroutines and channel

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func boring(msg string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; ; i++ {
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", msg, i)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1e3)) * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    return c
}
func main() {
    c := fanInNew(boring("joe"), boring("anh"))
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
    fmt.Println("You both are boring, I am leaving")
}

func fanInNew(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    for {
        select {
        case s := <-input1:
            c <- s
        case s := <-input2:
            c <- s
        }
    }
    return c
}
```

If i run this program it is giving me error, all goroutines are asleep, deadlock.

But If I put `select` inside anonymous goroutine, it works just fine. Working example:

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func boring(msg string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; ; i++ {
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", msg, i)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1e3)) * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    return c
}
func main() {
    c := fanInNew(boring("joe"), boring("anh"))
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
    fmt.Println("You both are boring, I am leaving")
}

func fanInNew(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case s := <-input1:
                c <- s
            case s := <-input2:
                c <- s
            }
        }
    }()
    return c
}
```

Can you please help me to understand reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 3):

The `for` statements loops forever, and so the `<-c` chan is never passed along and the chans get filled, but the `main` thread gets stuck waiting for `c := fanInNew(a, b)`.

`fanInNew()` **never returns** because `for` **loops forever** (and **blocks on `select`** btw):

```
func fanInNew(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    for { // Loop forever and read from inputs 1 and 2
        select {
        case s := <-input1:
            c <- s
        case s := <-input2:
            c <- s            
        }
    }
    return c
}
```

Then in the **main thread** this function never returns the `c` chan.

```
func main() {
    // Never gets passed the next line
    c := fanInNew(boring("joe"), boring("anh"))
}
```

So you can put the `for` loops themselves in goroutines, as you did in the second example. *Also* typically goroutines should return, either because you pass a message in (such as by `close()`ing), or because they reach a return statement.

In any case, what you have in the 2nd example is great for demonstrating the use of anonymous **closures**. The `chan` passed into the goroutine can be returned elsewhere and enable safe message passing between threads:

```
c := make(chan string)
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case s := <-input1:
            c <- s
        case s := <-input2:
            c <- s
        }
    }
}()
return c
```

There are a few ways of ending a for loop in an anonymous goroutine, including select on a second `chan`, a **closing channel**, which when `close()`ed you can return. Also, typically [`WaitGroups`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup) can achieve that.

Comment: Then how does `for` loop return when I put it in goroutines. ? Thanks

Comment: You can pass another `chan` of and empty struct, a closing channel. But `WaitGroups` work well too